# How can i make my turn my text file to 40x40 matrix

Tags: java, arrays

In my code i need to read my text file and create a 40x40 matrix however my array only reads the first line Here is my code;

```
    String worldData = "world.txt";
    File worldFile = new File(worldData);
    int[][] worldArray = new int[40][40];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(worldFile);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String allText = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] allLines = allText.split(";");
        for (int i = 0; i < worldArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < worldArray[0].length; j++) {

                worldArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(allLines[0]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does your text file have at least 40 lines and is each line contain at least 40 tokens delimited by a semicolon? If so I would suggest you use the current while loop you have to increment the row in worldArray (i.e index _i_ ), and then when you split the array, use an inner loop over the tokens for the columns in worldArray (i.e. index _j_). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that every line contains a row of the world matrix, the for-i loop should read exactly one line.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(worldFile);
for (int i = 0; i < worldArray.length; i++) {
    if (!scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There are only " + i
               + " lines of the 40 needed.");
    }
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] cells = line.split(";");
    if (cells.length != 40) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There are " + i
               + " cells instead of the 40 needed.");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < worldArray[0].length; j++) {
        worldArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(cells[j]);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can do without a Scanner:

```
String worldData = "world.txt";
Path worldFile = Paths.get(worldData);
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(worldFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
if (lines.size() < 40) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("There are only "
            + lines.size()
           + " lines of the 40 needed.");
}
for (int i = 0; i < worldArray.length; i++) {
    String line = lines.get(i);
    String[] cells = line.split(";");
    if (cells.length != 40) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There are " + i
               + " cells instead of the 40 needed.");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < worldArray[0].length; j++) {
        worldArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(cells[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope the in-line comment may give you some hints:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { 
    // you read a single line once in the while loop
    String allText = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] allLines = allText.split(";");
    // here, for every new coming line, the for loop starts
    // from array[0][0], therefore, it overwrites all the existing 
    // data. Thus, finally, you have only the last line in your array.
    for (int i = 0; i < worldArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < worldArray[0].length; j++) {

            worldArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(allLines[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all thank you. I understood and delete the for loop but my String array that i stored the all lines only takes the first row for some reason

Comment: @MUHAMMETTAYYİPHAKANUTUŞ I don't think just removing the for loops is gonna solve your problem. But anyway, you've known the cause to your problem. The next step would be: fix it. I think this is your part. You should think about how to handle the indexes, if you prefer playing with them.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are good. Here you can try this to reduce loop operations and easily get integers from file without parsing String to Integer. Use delimiter with scanner object.

```
String worldData = "world.txt";
File worldFile = new File(worldData);
int[][] worldArray = new int[40][40];
int i = 0; // For index of worldArray
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(worldFile).useDelimiter("[\\n;]");
while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
        wA[i/40][i%40] = sc.nextInt();
        i++;
/* Since worldArray is a square matrix, you can keep 
incrementing i and divide i by 40 to get rows index and i%40 to get column index thus simplifying the code.*/
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use BufferedReader to read line by line from the file

```
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("world.txt"));
            String line = null;
            while((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                // process your line
            }
            br.close();
```